# Output all variables in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to output all of the variables in my script along with their values.

The for statement below works for the variables that are not in the function. How do I get the values of the variables inside the function? Specifically k12, which I would expect to output: `var k12 = 25`

```
var labor_rate = 25;
var k1 = labor_rate

function myFunction() {
    var labor_rate2 = 25;
    var k12 = labor_rate2
}

// output all variables
var variables = {};
for(var b in window) {
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        console.log(b+" = "+window[b]);
        variables[b] = window[b];
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're just trying to inspect the state of your program for education/debugging purposes, you should use a debugger for this. You cannot get "all variables" in the entire script.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Did you mean to *invoke* `myFunction` somewhere?  Did you mean to attach its local variables to the `window` object?

Comment: @David Yes, I meant to invoke the function. I'm trying to check the value of all variables in the script.

Comment: Why don't you just store the variables as property key/values of an object?

Comment: @Tom: You seem to be drastically misunderstanding what "scope" is and how it works.  There is no central repository of "all variables in the script".  If you were to invoke `myFunction` (which the code doesn't do) then it would create two local variables during the execution of the function.  When the function execution ends, those variables are no longer in scope and no longer exist.  So your current code successfully *does* "check the value of all variables in the script" in the sense that it shows all variables which exist currently in scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and it doesn't make sense to want to.

The variables in `myFunction` don't exist, unless the thread of execution is *in* `myFunction`. When the thread of execution leaves the function, those variables cease to exist.

At the point in time where you're printing variables, the variables you're looking for don't exist and don't have a value for you to print, even if you're previously invoked the function.

Comment: I need to output the value of all variables because I'm taking a large Excel file and lots of formulas into JS. I need to make sure the variables/formulas are all doing what they should be doing.

Comment: @Tom Then again, use a debugger, or local log statements. It makes no sense to try to print the values of variables that no longer exist. Variables are temporal - they come into existence, and then they are destroyed, over time. You can't, at the end of your script, out the value of every variable that ever existed. If you need the values to persist indefinitely, make them global, but this is generally a terrible practice just to get the visibility that your debugger gives you.